# selecting an element that has been scrolled to

Tags: jquery, scroll, selector

I have a scrolling site that uses the Jquery ScrollTo plugin. What I am trying to do is to select an element within the section that has just been scrolled to so that I can animate it once the element is visible on screen.
suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the top of the element and compare with document scrollTop in the onAfter event of scrollTo plugin.

```
$("div").scrollTo({
  onAfter: function(){//This is the callback function when the scrolling animation is complete.
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var scrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
  var elementWidth = $("div").find("elementToFind").width();
  var elementOffset = $("div").find("elementToFind").offset();
  var elementTop = elementOffset.top;
  var elementLeft =elementOffset.left;

  if((elementTop > scrollTop) && (elementTop < $(window).height() + scrollTop) &&
     ( elementLeft > scrollLeft) && ( (elementLeft + elementWidth) < $(window).width() + scrollLeft)){
    //The element is visible do something here
  } 
}

  });
})
```

Comment: @Devender - Check my edited answer, it will work now for horizontally scrolling site also.

Comment: Ok I think I have the code right however its not working here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/ymtww/

Comment: I dont see any markup in the fiddle and also jquery is also not selected.

Comment: how should I show you the code if JS fiddle isnt working? comments arent long enough

Comment: Did you try in your application/

Comment: In the fiddle you will have to include scrollTo plugin also in order to make it work

Comment: For you to understand the logic I have created the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bhLUE/5/. Take a look. Try to scroll the page and you will see h3 become visible when it is in the view.

Comment: Thanks so much. make sense to do it that way.